# How to achieve parallelism with threads when calling the multiple webservices

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, rest, asynchronous

i have a scenario where i have multiple web services to be called within a method . i want to call these REST services in asynchronous way and i have to achieve parallelism using threads .
what i mean is , if 5 rest services needs to be called , call them asynchronously so that each of the 5 rest clients run on 5 different thread .

i thought of using Apache HttpAsyncClients . However, HttpAsyncClient does not use multiple threads for each web service  internally. will this help me accomplish my requirement ? or is there any way to accomplish .

Comment: Consider using `AsyncHttpClient`, which doesn't even occupy a thread per reuest. It uses Java NIO's native support for asynchronous I/O.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but if each rest ws is served by a servlet or ejb, isn't going already be served by a pool of instances? I mean, the idea of having a pool isn't exactly to provide parallelism without exhausting resources?